# jQuery array.push inside each function is returning array result as reverse

Tags: jquery

The checkbox names and values I'm selecting in order is `["C3","B2","A1"] and ["3","2","1"]`.

```
var selected_card_result = [];
var selected_card_name = []; 
$.each($("input[class='test']:checked"), function(){            
selected_card_result.push($(this).val());
selected_card_name.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
 console.log(selected_card_name);
 console.log(selected_card_result);
```

But, finally I'm getting after outside the loop as in reverse like below,

```
selected_card_name =["A1","B2","C3"];
selected_card_result=["3","2","1"];
```

Please some one help me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds odd, can you post a [MCVE] in a runnable Stack Snippet so we can see the strangeness for ourselves?

Comment: please share html

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding regarding checkbox is not correct. When you try to fetch value of the selected checkbox, it will give the value in the order of option, but not in the order of your selection.

Ex : CarBikeBus

In the above example, Even if you select Bus first than Car, you will get Car first than the Bus.

To fetch in the order of your selection, you have to write your own logic. Please Write a different question regarding that. If you want I can help you out. Thank You. Hala,Happy Coding :-)

Comment: I have pushed checked value into array but the array order of checkbox selection after push is wrong. That is the issue I'm facing.

Comment: I still unable to understand your requirement.Can you please clarify these:
1. Are you trying to push the selected option into the array in the order of user selection ? OR 
2. Are you just trying to push the selected option into array. ?

Comment: If you are trying to achieve (1), Please share the complete code where you tracking the ORDER in which user selects. IF you try (2), You already wrote the code,It should work